# Clang scan-build fails to find infinite loop

Tags: c, infinite-loop, clang-static-analyzer

I made a trivial typo in the following loop:

```
do{
    ys = (ys*ys + 1)%n;
    d = egcd(x > y ? x - y : y - x, n, NULL, NULL);
}while(d == 1);
```

This loop is part of a Pollard-Rho-Brent factorization algorithm with gcd aggregation.  That guarantees it will terminate where it occurs in the larger program.  However, the trivial typo of `y` instead of `ys` means the loop will never terminate since the change in `ys` is never reflected in `d`.  However, `scan-build` fails to identify this problem.  Initially I thought this was because it did not know `egcd` was a pure function.  (`egcd` returns the gcd of the first two arguments and outputs Bezout coefficients to the second two if they are nonnull.)  However, even if I comment out that line of the loop so `d` is not modified, `scan-build` fails to report an infinite loop.  Is there a way to get `scan-build` to report this kind of error, or is there another open source static analyzer that I can use?  I'm surprised commenting out the second line doesn't give any warning, I'm sure I've seen a warning for a similar mistake with nested for loops on `i` and `j` where `i` is incremented in both but the checks are still correct.

Edit: it doesn't matter what `egcd` is.  The definition is

```
int64_t egcd(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t *_t, int64_t *_s){
    int64_t r0 = b, r1 = a;
    int64_t s0 = 1, s1 = 0;
    int64_t t0 = 0, t1 = 1;
    while(r1){
        int64_t q = r0/r1, t;
        t = r1;
        r1 = r0 - q*r1;
        r0 = t;
        t = s1;
        s1 = s0 - q*s1;
        s0 = t;
        t = t1;
        t1 = t0 - q*t1;
        t0 = t;
    }
    if(_t){
        *_t = t0;
    }
    if(_s){
        *_s = s0;
    }
    return r0;
}
```

but it could just be `#define egcd(a, b, t, s) (a)==(b)?a:1` or even `#define egcd(a, b, c, d) 2` or the line using it could be commented out, and the clang static analyzer would still not recognize this as an infinite loop.

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  . The code as posted cannot be proven to be  an infinite loop because the `egcd` function could return a value other than `1`.

Comment: The code still does not contain a Minimal Reproducible Example. It is important to post code that demonstrates the problem so that other people can try to reproduce it in order to help solve the problem.   If the problem occurs with lines commented out, then delete those lines, check the problem still occurs, and post that version of the code.  This is explained in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: If I remove the assignment of `d` completely and run a `clang-tidy` check I get: `this loop is infinite; none of its condition variables (d) are updated in the loop body [bugprone-infinite-loop]`. However even if I do something as simple as `d = 1` the warning is no longer generated. This might be a shortcut in how the analyzer works (it sees that `d` is updated inside the loop and considers things to be ok), or maybe a bug.

Comment: @M.M yes, but in this and many other cases, removing lines like the `d` assignment cause a different but similar error to manifest.  The particular implementation of `egcd` doesn't matter, but you're right that I should have included it so the snippet could compile.  The two snippets of code are now sufficient to compile an object file so I think they constitute a complete example of the kind of erroneous infinite loop I hope to detect.

Comment: @icebp indeed, I think clang-tidy is mostly a linter.  I don't know if it does any static analysis, even the reverse dataflow analysis required to find the loop condition is a loop invariant (and the body of the loop has no side effects, meaning we encounter ub if it is an infinite loop).

Comment: @hacatu it can do the clang static analyzer checks (I only used `clang-tidy` here because I had a project already configured and it was easy to drop in the code from the question). I had the `clang-analyzer-` checks enabled which should enable all the Clang Static Analyzer checks. My point is that in some simple cases the infinite loop is detected, but as soon as the loop gets slightly more complicated the analyzer is fooled.